# How can I includes a reusable workflow locally?

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a github action that `uses` another workflow from the same repo locally. But the job doesn't find the reusable workflow yml file from the repo.

The file structure:

```
.github/workflows/common/affected.yml
.github/workflows/main_pr.yml
```

In mina_pr.yml:

```
name: CI
on:
  pull_request:
    types:
      - opened
      - closed
      - synchronize
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  callAffectedApps:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    uses: ./.github/workflows/affected.yml
    outputs:
      affected: ${{ steps.affectedApps.outputs.AFFECTED_APPS }}
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
     
  
  is_even_buid:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: callAffectedApps
    if: contains(needs.callAffectedApps.outputs.affected, 'is-event')
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      
      - run: |
          ls
```

The error I got is:

```
Can't find 'action.yml', 'action.yaml' or 'Dockerfile' under '/home/runner/work/mono-repo-demo/mono-repo-demo/.github/workflows/common/affected.yml'. Did you forget to run actions/checkout before running your local action?
```

The file does exist and committed. The job includes a checkout as well `actions/checkout@v3`.  I am not sure why it says not found. The repo is: https://github.com/zhaoyi0113/mono-repo-demo/actions/runs/6244869282

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reusable workflows should be added at `job.*` level, not `job.*.steps` level.

In your setup, GitHub thinks you are trying to use an action, which is why it looks for `action.yml` in *directory* named like your workflow *filename*.

```yaml
jobs:
 callAffectedApps:
  uses: ./.github/workflows/common/affected.yml
```

Comment: I have tried that but got an error: `Cannot define both `uses` and `steps` at the same time for the following jobs: callAffectedApps`.  The step is used to checkout the code but it seems I can't combine them in one job?

Comment: @JoeyYiZhao Main workflow only defines which other workflows it wants to use (plus some settings for them). It's just metadata, you can't run anything at this point. Details such as calling `actions/checkout` should be a part of job(s) inside reusable workflow.